# How to find out type of manipulation in windows store app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm handling `ManipulationCompleted` event in my control in windows rt application.
But `ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs` has no information about type of manipulation executed. How to find out was it a pinch or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what specifically you'd like to find out. The [`Cumulative`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationcompletedroutedeventargs.cumulative.aspx) property shows what was done overall in the manipulation and so the `Scale` field will tell you if scaling happened which is a result of a pinch gesture. Really though you should be handling `ManipulationDelta` and immediately responding to each delta event. `ManipulationCompleted` is where you'd perhaps run a snap animation or something of that sort. For more detailed information about where each finger touches the screen you could look at the `Pointer~` events.